# Can you run a JavaScript file in PyCharm Community Edition?

Tags: javascript, pycharm

I am doing a REST API tutorial where I use a JavaScript file to make AJAX calls to the API endpoints. I have pretty much everything built out but the JavaScript won't run and I think it's because PyCharm's Community Edition doesn't allow JS files. I am able to run CSS files.

Comment: I think [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/running-and-debugging-javascript.html) should help?

Comment: even though Pycharm won't run js by itself, you can make it run on your pc normally using any other environment and call said environment via Pycharm.
For example. if you localHost a DjangoProject, you can 'runserver' via PyCharm and all .js inside it will work even on community ed. (you wont have the cool editing features to js tho, so I edit them on a separate free IDE and copy-paste into my Django project)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, PyCharm's Community Edition does not allow for you to run JavaScript.

[You can learn more here](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html) but only the professional version allows JavaScript to run.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a new question, but I stumbled upon it while searching for similiar issue, a work around that can be used, in case NodeJS is installed on the machine, is to go to

1. Open 'Edit Run/Debug configuration' dialog
2. Edit Configurations...
3. Add New Configuration
4. Shell Script
5. Script text

and in the field Script text enter `node FileName.js`. Save the configuration and run it everytime you need to run the JavaScript file.